# Merging MySQL row entries into a single row

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables, one for `listings` and another representing a list of `tags` for the `listings` table.

In the `listings` table the tag ids are stored in a field called `tags` as 1-2-3-. This has worked out very well for me (regular expressions and joins to separate and display the data), but I now need to pull the titles of those tags into a single row. See below.

```
listings table
id    tags
1     1-2-3-
2     4-5-6-


tags table
id    title
1     pig
2     dog
3     cat
4     mouse
5     elephant
6     duck
```

And what I need to produce out of the `listings` table is:

```
id     tags
2      mouse, elephant, duck
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query that could help. But since it is doing some string operations, it may not be as good as a regular join:

```
select l.id, group_concat( t.title ) 
   from listings l, tags t 
   where concat( '-', l.tags )  like concat( '%-', t.id, '-%' ) group by l.id ;
```

Comment: MY version from your version:

SELECT l.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.title)
FROM listing l, tags t
WHERE l.tags REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',t.id,'[[:>:]]')
GROUP BY l.id ;

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, with your tags stored in this denormalized format, there's no easy way to go from 1-2-3 to the corresponding tags.  In other words, there's no simple way to split out the ids, join to another table and then recombine.  Your best option would be to create a `listing_tag` table with two columns

```
listing_id    tag_id
1             1
1             2
1             3
2             4
2             5
2             6
```

and then it's just a simple join:

```
SELECT listing_id, GROUP_CONCAT(title SEPARATOR ', ') FROM listing_tag JOIN tags ON tags.id = tag_id
```

Comment: But now your sitting with multiple entries in the listing table?

Comment: @Derrick, yes this does duplicate some data but it follows a well established normalization practice that makes many other things much simpler: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT() + INNER JOIN + GROUP BY

Comment: That works great for a single row result, Im trying to get it to work with multiple rows.